# Fetch file type/extension from binary data

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-type

**File.py**

```
file = fields.Binary('File')

@api.multi
def get_file(self):
    if self.file:
        xsl_file  = base64.decodestring(self.file)
        m = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_MIME)
        print 'fffffffffffffff',m.file(xsl_file) //prints None
        print 'fffffffffffffff',m.file(self.file) //prints None
    print self.file //Prints binary string.
```

**Binary string**
     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'

My question is, How to find file extension from this binary string?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution:

***.py**

```
file = fields.Binary('File')
file_fname = fields.Char(string='File name')
```

***.xml**

```
<field widget="binary" height="64" name="file" filename="file_fname" required="1"/>
<field name="file_fname" invisible="1" />
```

The name of file will be saved in `file_fname` field.

And used `splitext` method to extract extension from file name.

```
@api.onchange('file')
@api.depends('file','file_fname')
def check_file_type(self):
    if self.file:
        filename,filetype = os.path.splitext(self.file_fname)
        if filetype not in ['.xls','.csv']:
            raise UserError(_('Invalid file type!!!\n Choose excel or csv file format.'))
```